# I am writing a program to copy a file into another directory, but the copied name is not the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, byte

Here is my code.

```
import sys
import os

usersFile = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")

if not os.path.exists("recv"):
    os.makedirs("recv")

copiedFile = open("recv/" + str(usersFile), "wb")

byteChunk = usersFile.read(1000)
while (byteChunk):
    copiedFile.write(byteChunk)
    byteChunk = usersFile.read(1000)

usersFile.close()
copiedFile.close()
```

This is in Python3, and the issue I am having is the file does get copied over byte by byte, and it is in the right directory, but the file is named `<_io.BufferedReadername = 'Test.jpg'>`

I just need it to be named Test.jpg which is the file I copied.

This program was called like this:

> python3 programName.py Test.jpg

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to concatenate paths.

Comment: You can however file a disassociation request via the [contact](/contact) form.

Answer (score 2):

`usersFile` is not a file name but an open file object. Replace `str(usersFile)` with `sys.argv[1]`.